# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP with Zend

Tags: php, html, oop, foreach

I'm currently working on a Languages module with Zend 1.12 (having never previously worked on it before) and keep getting the title error with the following code.

```
<?php if(count($this->getContent('languages')) == 0) : ?>
        <tr><td>No languages were found.</td></tr>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getContent('languages') as $language) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $language['language_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language['iso_shortcode']; ?></td>
```

The getContent() method is this:

```
public function getContent($key) {
    if(isset($this->content[$key])) {
        return $this->content[$key];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A colleague has done an address module the exact same way with success, so I'm wondering could this be a database issue maybe? I've checked the database and everything seems to be corresponding.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Like: `var_dump($this->getContent('languages'));` ? If it is false, you got your problem.

Comment: When the error complains about an invalid argument to `foreach`, it's a good idea to examine the argument you are passing to `foreach`. Also known as "debugging".

Comment: I ran a print_r and nothing got returned.

Comment: The problem you have is that the array not exist

Comment: @CiaranReen `print_r` doesn't show anything when false is returned, `var_dump` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your getContent() method returns false if the specified key does not exist; there are a number of potential problems with this:

1) What if it were valid for an entry in the content member variable to have the value false? Were you actually checking the result, you could not distinguish between absence of the key and a key found with value false. A better choice to indicate absence of an entry would be null, or you could throw an exception.

2) In your use of getContent(), you have assumed that there will be a result for the key 'languages', but have failed to code defensively for the eventuality where there isn't, as has most likely happened here. It would be better either to check that the languages key exists before calling getContent(), to assign the result to a variable and then process it only if it has the expected value (e.g. is not null or is an array in this case), or to throw an exception.

3) A way to mitigate these issues would be with a default parameter to getContent(). The default value would be returned if the expected key does not exist, ensuring that calling code would always work. The default value in this case would be array().

4) As it may be indicative of a bug for a key not to exist, a final nice touch would be either a 3rd parameter to getContent() that specified whether or not the key should exist, or if the default value for the default parameter was e.g. null, to throw an exception if the passed default value was null and the key was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea how to solve this, or at least taking care of this problem:

```
<?php if(count($this->getContent('languages')) == 0) : ?>
    <tr><td>No languages were found.</td></tr>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getContent('languages') as $language) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $language['language_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $language['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $language['iso_shortcode']; ?></td>
```

what you can do, is remove this line

```
if(count($this->getContent('languages')) == 0)
```

and replace is by

```
if (!$this->getContent('languages'))
```

This just checks if the returned value is false, if the returned array is empty, the foreach just does nothing, so that won't be a problem.  Or:

```
if (!is_array($this->getContent('languages')))
```

Which checks if the returned value is not an array.